NFSv4 persistent (>1h) wrong cache?
The problem is a bit complicated to explain, but I will try to do so as clearly as possible.
I have access to a highly available NAS managed by a hosting provider. Several servers mount this NAS via the NFSv4 protocol (specifically v4.2).
Sometimes (this happens rather rarely, but frequently enough to be noticeable) when server1 modifies a file, server2 still sees the old content of the file but with updated attributes (the modification date corresponds to when server1 made the changes to the file).
An example of console output would be:
~ $ ssh server1 -- "hostname && date && md5sum /nas1/test.json && sleep 180 && md5sum /nas1/test.json && cat /nas1/test.json"

server1
Tue Jun 11 07:40:20 AM CEST 2024
2e0734735755b04f27cb02fea643166a  /nas1/test.json
2e0734735755b04f27cb02fea643166a  /nas1/test.json
{ "date": "2024-06-10T19:01:26" }

~ $ ssh server2 -- "hostname && date && md5sum /nas1/test.json && sleep 180 && md5sum /nas1/test.json && cat /nas1/test.json"

server2
Tue Jun 11 07:40:30 AM CEST 2024
ace2e8b507718d96318fd52165ec6b11  /nas1/test.json
ace2e8b507718d96318fd52165ec6b11  /nas1/test.json
{ "date": "2024-06-09T17:30:55" }

The true content of the file is the one displayed by server1, as it is the server that made the last modification to the file (replacing "2024-06-09T17:30:55" with "2024-06-10T19:01:26").
The content displayed by server2 is incorrect, here for at least 3 minutes, but it can last several hours.
A stat on the same file from these two servers returns up-to-date information for both servers:
~ $ ssh server1 -- "stat /nas1/test.json"
  File: /nas1/test.json
  Size: 439773          Blocks: 1041       IO Block: 131072 regular file
Device: 0,51    Inode: 74454718    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  309/  user)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
Access: 2024-03-11 15:08:44.877240000 +0100
Modify: 2024-06-10 21:01:28.306099000 +0200
Change: 2024-06-10 21:01:28.306099000 +0200
 Birth: -

~ $ ssh server2 -- "stat /nas1/test.json"
  File: /nas1/test.json
  Size: 439773          Blocks: 1041       IO Block: 131072 regular file
Device: 0,51    Inode: 74454718    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  309/  user)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
Access: 2024-03-11 15:08:44.877240000 +0100
Modify: 2024-06-10 21:01:28.306099000 +0200
Change: 2024-06-10 21:01:28.306099000 +0200
 Birth: -

On 100 files modified in the same way, I encounter the problem on a few files (sometimes none). The issue is quite random.
I have already tried, in vain, the different options and a combination of the following options (in NFSv4):

ro
noac
lookupcache=none

I attempted to use the latest available version of the NFS client, but this did not resolve the issue.
I tried capturing network traffic to see what happens, and on server2, the file content is not found in the network frames. I suspect server 2 is using a local cache.
I enabled the debug options for the NFS driver at the kernel level with sysctl sunrpc.nfs_debug=0xFFFF
But I did not find anything conclusive (I am not an expert in reading these traces).
In NFSv3, the problem does not exist.
It looks very similar to the bug described here, but it doesn't seem to be related:
https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/11/14/how-we-spent-two-weeks-hunting-an-nfs-bug/
Does anyone have any idea where this mysterious problem might be coming from, any leads to explore, or elements to resolve it?

I would use Wireshark to see if the file's change attribute is changing or not. You can configure dumpcap for rolling window capture and look into packets when the problem pops. My assumption is that the change attribute is not updated, and the file system cache is not invalidated (sounds line issue on the server side).

Thank you, I've already tried to make network captures. In the network captures, I see file attributes exchange but not the file content exchange.
What are you referring to when you say "change attribute is not updated"? Aren't the file attributes (among other things) what you see when you do a stat on the file? As indicated in my message, the attributes on the 2 servers are up to date.
I agree with your conclusion: system cache not invalidated. By forcing the cache cleanup via echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches or a direct read via the O_DIRECT flag, I can access the updated file.

If you look with Wireshark, then the reply to the GETATTR operation should include reqd_attr: Change (3) that changes every time the the file is changed. I assume that this attribute is not updated by the server and lets the client think that the cached value is still valid.

Once again, thank you for the precious help !
Regarding the reqd_attr: Change (3) attribute change, this number is updated each time the file is modified, regardless of client read requests. Is this correct?
I retrieved a network capture at the time of a problem, I have a changeid of 8013827. If I make a read request with the O_DIRECT flag to access the correct file contents, I get the same changeid. Should I wait for the problem to occur again before checking the changeid?
